# Trying to create or remove Watermarks depending on filename

Tags: vba, ms-word, watermark

I need an 'autorun' piece of VBA for Word 2013 to either add or remove a Watermark dependent on the filename of the document. I want to add this to a template we use for our Technical Reports which, in turn, are generated by an external Application/System and automatically named in the process. So the same document template may be named differently dependent on workflow

For documents entitled "DRAFT.XXX.NNNNNNNN.." I want a 'Draft' watermark
For any other documents there should be no watermark (or the watermark could be coloured white, ie invisible)

I've successfully created VBA/Macros to insert or remove Watermarks:

```
Sub InsertWaterMark()
    Dim strWMName As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    'selects all the sheets
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Select
    strWMName = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Index
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    'Change the text for your watermark here
    Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.AddTextEffect(msoTextEffect1, _
    "DRAFT", "Arial", 1, False, False, 0, 0).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange
        .Name = strWMName
        .TextEffect.NormalizedHeight = False
        .Line.Visible = False
        With .Fill
            .Visible = True
            .Solid
            .ForeColor.RGB = Gray
            .Transparency = 0.5
        End With
        .Rotation = 315
        .LockAspectRatio = True
        .Height = InchesToPoints(2.42)
        .Width = InchesToPoints(6.04)
        With .WrapFormat
            .AllowOverlap = True
            .Side = wdWrapNone
            .Type = 3
        End With
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
        'If using Word 2000 you may need to comment the 2
        'lines above and uncomment the 2 below.
        '        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
        '        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
        .Left = wdShapeCenter
        .Top = wdShapeCenter
    End With
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occured trying to insert the watermark." & Chr(13) & _
    "Error Number: " & Err.Number & Chr(13) & _
    "Decription: " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
End Sub

Sub RemoveWaterMark()
    Dim strWMName As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Select
    strWMName = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Index
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes(strWMName).Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    'MsgBox "An error occured trying to remove the watermark." & Chr(13) & _
    '"Error Number: " & Err.Number & Chr(13) & _
    '"Decription: " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
End Sub
```

I've created an AutoOpen macro which checks the first five characters of the document for `"DRAFT"`, `"Draft"` or `"draft"` and then it should call the appropriate Subroutine:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Dim oldfilename As String
    Dim draft As String
    oldfilename = ActiveDocument.Name
    draft = Left(oldfilename, 5)
    Select Case draft
    Case "DRAFT", "Draft", "draft"
        Call InsertWaterMark
    Case Else
        Call RemoveWaterMark
    End Select
Exit Sub
```

BUT I'm getting an error when the code branches to the InsertWatermark Subroutine and the line

```
.Name = strWMName
```

I then get an error:

> An error occurred trying to insert the watermark. Error Number: 70  Description: Permission denied

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert Integer which comes from `.Sections(1).Index` property into string. Two suggestions:

```
.Name = Cstr(strWMName)
```

or

```
.Name = "WaterMarkName" & strWMName
```

Please remember to change accordingly in `RemoveWaterMark` subroutine.